# How to make a histogram with percent

Tags: python, pandas

I have a "members" dataframe where there is a success column and a sex column. I would like to make a histogram that would represent the percentage of successful women and the percentage of successful men. I manage to get the number of successes for both sexes but they have to be updated with the number of men and women otherwise it is not representative. Do you have any idea how to do this?

code :

-dataframe

```
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
print(members)
```

-inconclusive test

```
sns.histplot(data=members, x="sex", y="success", stat='percent')
```

Comment: What _specifically_ is wrong with your current output?

Comment: my goal is to have this result but in a histogram : ("Le pourcentage de femmes ayant réussi est de",int(len(femmessuccess)/len(femmes)*100),"%")
print("Le pourcentage d'hommes ayant réussi est de",int(len(hommessuccess)/len(hommes)*100),"%")

Comment: But I don't know how to have that and with what I've done, it doesn't return something great (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a graph showing the percentage according to `sex` and `success`, I created a dataframe grouping the values of `sex` and looking for the normalized quantity with `value.counts(normalize=True)` to create a DataFrame.

```py
members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
df_members = members.groupby('sex')['success'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).rename('percent').reset_index()
df_members
```

Dataframe :

[image: Dataframe]

Then I used sns.catplot to put `sex` on the X axis and `percent` on the Y axis, separating by success.

```py
sns.catplot(data = df_members, x='sex', y = 'percent',kind='bar', hue='success')
```

[image: Seaborn]

Comment: Thank you much, it's exactly what I wanted to do !

Comment: Great! In this case, we use the bar graph instead of the histogram. I recommend this reading to differentiate between them: https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-histogram-and-bar-graph.html

Comment: Ok thank you, I will read it